Polygons on Lightning Map on ZipCode areas
I'm attempting to illustrate a specific Zip Code area using a colored polygon to fill the region within the zip code boundary.
My attempt: Currently I'm able to plot them only using markers. This serves my purpose as I do not have to use api keys.

Although I understand that utilizing an API would be necessary for the Google Maps approach, but the majority of my task is accomplished with the code provided below.
Problem statement: Is there a possibility to add different polygon colour to fill the various zip code boundaries instead of markers. With my research I'm unable to update this
 <lightning-map
       map-markers={mapMarkersList}
       options={mapOptions}>
 </lightning-map>
                    

and
this.mapMarkers = this.contacts.map(contact => ({
location: {
       PostalCode: contact.Elephant_Zip__c
},
title: contact.Elephant_Name__c,
       description: `my Zip: ${contact.Elephant_Zip__c}`
}));

Not sure how to get the lat and lan like in the Salesforce documentation as below:

Any suggestion or direction will be much appreciated!

As you noticed you can use type=Polygon for this.
You can activate GeoCode on Standard Objects like Leads, Accounts and Contact using a standard feature thats documented here.
The other options are using the Salesforce Maps, a paid feature.
With this you can use below code
// Create and add an address.
 String salesforceAddress = '415 Mission Street, San Francisco, CA 94105 USA';

 Map<string,object> options = new Map<String,Object> {
        'version' => '1', // Required. Version of the API endpoint. Must be '1'.
        'address' => salesforceAddress
    };

// Call the Geocode() method with the address.
  Map<String, Object> response = maps.API.Geocode(options);

// Log the resulting geographical coordinates and formatted address. 
  system.debug(response);

Finally if nothing works for you, you can sign up for a googles API service for map and use below code
public class GoogleMapsGeocodeApi {
 
  public string geocode(String address){
    String url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='
        + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(address, 'UTF-8')
        + '&components=country:GB'
        + '&key=' + getGoogleMapsAPIKey();
    
    return getHttp(url);
  }

  private string getHttp(string url) {
    
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    req.setMethod('GET');
    req.setEndpoint(url);
    req.setTimeout(120000);
    res = h.send(req); 

    return res.getBody();
  }

  private string getGoogleMapsAPIKey() {
    return ''; // get key from custom settings
  }

}

Of course the above is not PRODUCTION ready but should give you something to start with..

Hi Mohith. Thanks for your answer. I tried the way you suggested and on activating the integrations rules, the contact latitude and longitude populates from data.com which pretty slick considering there was no integration or API key involved. This will allow me to only plot a single point as its a (lat,long). I believe I would have to use google maps to use the polygon feature anyway to plot using many such points for a polygon. Accepting your answer. Thanks!
